# The Media module does not correctly render YouTube videos added with Media: YouTube

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, media

Trying to allow the user to embed YouTube videos from the [Wysiwyg](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg), CKEditor 3.6, [Media: YouTube](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_youtube).

This is the module config :

[image]

Then I try to add a YouTube video by providing the URL link to the video or the embed code (iframe etc)

Both versions print this code which obviously won't render a video (url in src ?)

```
<video class="media-element file-default" controls="controls" data-fid="36" data-media-element="1">
  <source src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxeb0cwjE8U" type="video/youtube">
</video>
```

I'm a front end dev and not that much experienced with Drupal. I can provide every information needed.

Any insights ?